# Scala Docs Implicit Class Example

Tags: scala

I'm looking at the implicit class example in the [Scala Docs](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/implicit-classes.html):

```
object Helpers {
 implicit class IntWithTimes(x: Int) {
  def times[A](f: => A): Unit = {
  def loop(current: Int): Unit =
    if(current > 0) {
      f
      loop(current - 1)
    }
  loop(x)
  }
 }
}
```

Can someone please explain this syntax and functionality?

```
times[A](f: => A)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`def times[A](f: => A): Unit`

is a function signature, where `A` is a generic type parameter. It is *unbound*, thus it can be `Any`'thing.

`f: =>` is a *by name* parameter. That is the f is not evaluated when the function `time` is called but only every time it is called within `time`.

[This](http://locrianmode.blogspot.de/2011/07/scala-by-name-parameter.html) is a good post about calling-by-name.

So in the example, if you have the implicit class in your scope you can do:

```
var count = 0
5 times { count += 1; println(count) }
```

and would get

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

as output.

Answer (score 1):

`times` is a polymorphic function which takes a single type parameter `A` and a single value parameter `f`. `f` is function which has result of type `A`. A function which takes another function as a parameter is called a higher-order function.

More info about these topics:

- http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/polymorphic-methods.html
- http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/higher-order-functions.html
- http://locrianmode.blogspot.sk/2011/07/scala-by-name-parameter.html